# Is there a way to get the BSD number of a device in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, bsd, device

My program reads device paths like `/dev/rdisk0` from input and then it looks in `IOKit` for a disk with the BSD name `disk0`. For this I have to remove `/dev/r` from the path.

Hard coding this path can break in future versions of Mac OS X. Therefore I though of another way: I could match the `IOService` using the BSD Major and Minor version of the device.

Here's my question: Is it possible to extract the BSD minor and major numbers from a path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Use the `stat` syscall.  The member of `struct stat` you are looking for is `st_dev`, which I believe is an OR of major and minor after a bit shift.

Comment: This works. `dev_t` is a 32 bit integer, the first 8 bits are the major version and the other 24 are the minor version. Is there a way to make this portable in case `dev_t` is changed to a 64bit integer?

Comment: in <sys/types.h> on my OpenBSD machine, there appear to be macros major() and minor() for this.

Comment: @ asveikau: Thanks, found them. I could swear that those functions weren't there yesterday when I looked for them.